# How to access a variable initialised in Parent Class using a Child object?

Tags: python, class

I have the following code:

```
class aa(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.height = 12

class bb(aa):
    def __init__(self):
        self.weight = 13

AA = aa()
BB = bb()
```

I am trying to access the variable initialized in the Parent class (aa), using the Child object as below.
Please suggest the correct way to do it as I am getting errors doing this way:

(If someone can point me to a good documentation on subclassing in Python, it would be great.)

```
print AA.height # 12
print BB.height # Error
```

Comment: you can find a good example here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly initialize the superclass. Edit your `__init__` method of `bb` such that it looks like this:

```
class bb(aa):
    def __init__(self):
        super(bb, self).__init__()  # Call the __init__ method of the superclass.
        self.weight = 13
```

It should then work:

```
print AA.height  # 12
print BB.height  # 12
```

---

As for the documentation on using superclasses, refer to the [`super`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) function in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You must call `__init__` from the superclass. It will not be called implicitly.

```
class bb(aa):
    def __init__(self):
        super(bb, self).__init__()
        self.weight = 13
```